# SQL Server Merge Replication - Excluding A Column From Replication

Tags: sql-server

Environment: One Head Office (HO) and 2 Stores (S1 and S2), SQL Server 2008 R2

**Goal**:

I need to exclude column `Password` (`varchar (30)`) from merge replication on table `Users`. The `Password` column needs to be local to where it is originally created (HO or S1 or S2). The POS application requires `Password` column in `Users` table to authenticate users. We need this column to be replicated as NULL on other locations.

Things I tried:

I excluded column `Password` from merge publication on table `Users` but when the snapshot agent works at S1 or S2 for the first time, it drops this column at subscribers. We need this column there.

I tried to ADD COLUMN back after snapshot is applied using snapshot post snapshot script but it fails saying that objects can't be altered at subscriber.

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replication creates stored procedures in the subscriber database(s) for inserting data. A sample stored procedure will look like the following:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_MSins_dboTable]
    @c1 int,
    @c2 int,
    @c3 varchar(256)
as
begin  
    insert into [dbo].[Table](
        [ID],
        [User],
        [Password]
    ) values (
    @c1,
    @c2,
    @c3 ) 
end
```

In the above example, you can alter the stored procedure and insert NULL instead of @c3. Now the catch is that the next time there is a a modification in the table's schema, the stored procedure will be recreated, so you have to determine if this is something that will work for you.